# Английская локализация в консоли разработчика GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play-console

При добавлении локализации приложения в консоли разработчика есть 7 видов английского языка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом приложении локализация `ru` и `en` без дополнительных спецификаторов.

**Вопрос**: если добавить в GP локализацию только для, например, `en-GB`, как будет отображаться текст в Канаде, Австралии или США? На английском или русском? Имеет ли смысл писать (копировать) текст (и картинки) для каждой `en` локализации или написать его для одной и он будет отображаться для всех англоязычных стран.

*(если честно, просто лениво каждый раз для каждой из 7 локализаций добавлять/менять картинки и текст)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно одного перевода. Он будет для всех региональных версий языка отображаться. Заниматься наполнением всех региональных вариаций нет смысла.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

При публикации приложения один язык идет дефолтным. Чаще всего это английский. Я могу ошибаться, но по-моему play market попробует подобрать схожий (В данном случае это все английские языке с небольшой разницей, поэтому он возмет один из существующих английских. При этом приоритетность мне не известна). Если языка нет вообще, то будет опубликован дефолтный. Опять-таки чащего всего это английский язык.

p/S/ публиковать для всех английских не нужно.